# In what version of javascript was bracket notation introduced for arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, version, compatibility, brackets

In what version of javascript was bracket notation introduced for arrays?

For example, I could declare an array like this ...

```
var something = new Array("one","two","three");
```

but this looks much neater ...

```
var something= ["one","two","three"];
```

But has the second style of notation always been in javascript?
Or was it added in a particular version? ie, version 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, etc

Comment: I would have up-voted this question however you blindly accepted *without* requiring documentation, references, *anything*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes. always there. in fact its recommended not to use the new Array and use [] instead.

Comment: thanks! will mark correct answer shortly (it says i have to wait 11 minutes lol)

Comment: i didn't downvote. i got also a downvote by someone. someone didn't like this whole page :) some people get angry or something during the morning.

Comment: yeah. people can get really strange on this website. i've had entire posts changed, removed, all sorts of things, where I thought it was a genuine question. I think people here can get a bit too proud sometimes. in any case, i find your answer short, simple, what i was looking for lol.

Comment: BAM! Down-voted. What was the year the documentation for the array API was released? Which browsers implemented it? Netscape 2? Obviously an irrelevant browser however there are some browsers that have taken *many* years to bother implementing stable standards that other browsers had long since implemented. Post that reference and I'll reverse the down-vote.

Comment: BAM!! Forget it. Go googling a bit.